# To retrieve old file name after rename

Tags: python, file, rename, file-handling, smb

I am currently working on a project where I have to verify whether file rename was successful after performing the rename operation. For example, I perform a rename operation on server using SMB protocol. After that I have to know whether it was successful? But this must be a different script than the one which connects and renames the file. Is there any file which stores history of files?

Comment: Does your renaming process move the file into a different directory?

Comment: No same location. But name will be different. So to check whether it was successful or not, I want to compare both old name and new name, later if it's not same then say successful.

Comment: Do you have any control over the script which connects and renames the file? Eg, can you get it to use a custom rename command which logs the old & new names?

Comment: Yeah. I have control of script but the rename command which I use was created by samba. So are you suggesting to edit their source file and create a new custom rename?

Comment: You probably don't need to change the script that connects and renames the file. You just need to arrange that it calls your rename script in place of the rename command it's currently using. And your  rename script can internally use the old rename command, if desired.

Comment: Yeah. You are right. But if you are familiar with Cisco WAAS box, it connects to router and there it operates to control the clients requests. I have to create a script for WAAS box which will keep a log of success or failure. But for now working on simple two laptops. One as server and another as client, here I run those script in client machine.